# Hibernate is not creating table Implicitly

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I m trying to create my first Spring MVC and HibernateTemplate Project.

Even though I mentioned hbm2ddl property to "create". It is not creating the table

Please help me and also suggest me to place the cfg.xml file in the right place

e

[image: Screenshot of my project structure]

Pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>in.co</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebms</artifactId>
    <name>eBMSiApp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--  Java assist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Spring ORM  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Servlet-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name = "annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>

        <!--     <mapping class = "in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate" /> -->
     <!--    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" /> -->
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id = "candidateDao" class = "in.co.ebms.iapp.dao.CandidateDao">
        <beans:property name = "hibernateTemplate" ref = "hibernateTemplate" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="in.co.ebms" />

</beans:beans>
```

Candidate.java model class

package in.co.ebms.iapp.model;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Candidate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Candidate(){

    }
    public Candidate(int id, String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + age;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Candidate other = (Candidate) obj;
        if (age != other.age)
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Candidate [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

CandidateDao.java

```
package in.co.ebms.iapp.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

import in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate;

public class CandidateDao {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    public void insert(Candidate candidate){
        hibernateTemplate.save(candidate);
    }

}
```

Test File

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

import in.co.ebms.iapp.dao.CandidateDao;

public class TestModel {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");
        CandidateDao dao = (CandidateDao) context.getBean("candidateDao");
        Candidate c = new Candidate(1,"Ansari",25);
        dao.insert(c);
        System.out.println("Succesfully inserted "+c);
    }
}
```

Error I am getting ( stacktrace )

```
INFO : org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@91993f: startup date [Sat Sep 17 11:49:38 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from file [D:\Workspace\eBMSip\eBMSiApp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\appServlet\servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1f57539: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,dataSource,sessionFactory,hibernateTemplate,candidateDao,homeController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String in.co.ebms.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Table 'test.candidate' doesn't exist
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate]; SQL [insert into Candidate (age, name) values (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:635)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:683)
    at in.co.ebms.iapp.dao.CandidateDao.insert(CandidateDao.java:22)
    at in.co.ebms.iapp.model.TestModel.main(TestModel.java:14)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [in.co.ebms.iapp.model.Candidate]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2853)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.candidate' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2334)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:56)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: If it's your first project, and not some old stuff to maintain, why do you use obsolete, unmaintained, years-old versions of Hibernate, Spring, servlet, etc. Why not use the most recent stable versions?

Comment: put also your configuration (cfg) file

Comment: table "candidate" does not exist. Drop your existing db tables and restart your app.

Comment: show your hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: I have not created hibernate.cfg.xml file. Instead I configured it inside servlet-context.xml file

Comment: I am using STS tool for creating Spring MVC Project. It by default creates with 3.1.1.Release of Spring. Any Idea to use latest version. Where I can find the proper document for spring mvc project with hibernateTemplate

Comment: There is nothing inside the hibernation e.cfg.xml file. Conifuguration is there inside servlet-context.xml file